# Tomcat - Failed to create work directory

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

After setting port to 80 from 8080 in server.xml, I'm getting this issue while starting tomcat 7 server.

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext postWorkDirectory
WARNING: Failed to create work directory [/var/lib/tomcat7/work/Catalina/localhost/service] for context [/service]
```

I have installed tomcat7 in digitalocen's ubuntu machine.

Comment: I think 08 is reserved  port. You can not use it for tomcat. Try to change it.

Comment: @Razib sorry it was 80, I changed it in question.